# How can I extract variables that change together?

Tags: r, count, poisson

I have a data.frame of variables that share the same date. Now, after performing Poisson on the count data, I want to determine the best way to extract those variables that meet this condition:

For variables that share a date, which variables see a change in value?

Please see repeatable environment, below (code section)

The closest I have come is filtering the data by 'Obs.date' variable, but given the data is 7000 obs long, I wonder if it is possible to do this...more efficiently.

```r
#Recreate data environment
set.seed(9999)
locations<-sample(LETTERS,20,replace = T)
startdate<-seq(as.Date('2018/01/01'), as.Date('2018/12/31'), by="day")
locations<-paste0('Location ', locations)
dat<-data.frame(
  Obs.date = sample(startdate,7000,replace = T),
  Obs.count = sample(0:6,7000,replace = T),
  Obs.loc = sample(locations,7000,replace = T),
  stringsAsFactors = F)

dfList<-split(dat,dat$Obs.loc)
a <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE), dfList)
b <- a[duplicated(a$Obs.date), ]

> head(b)
    Obs.date Obs.count    Obs.loc
2 2018-01-01         1 Location U
3 2018-01-01         1 Location Y
4 2018-01-01         2 Location D
5 2018-01-01         2 Location E
6 2018-01-01         2 Location F
7 2018-01-01         2 Location L
```

Expected result:
Dataframe/list that identifies patterns between `Obs.loc` & `Obs.count`. 

Put another way, are there any variables in the `Obs.loc`  that share a `Obs.date` value which see a change in `Obs.count`?

Example:

```r
#subset two dates
exB<-b %>% dplyr::filter(Obs.date=="2018-01-01" | Obs.date=="2018-01-02")

#output 
> str(exB)
'data.frame':   40 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Obs.date : Date, format: "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" ...
 $ Obs.count: int  1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ Obs.loc  : chr  "Location U" "Location Y" "Location D" "Location E" ...
```

We see that, from this minor subset, `exB` contains 40obs. I would like to know if any of the observations within `Obs.loc` and `Obs.count` are related. For example, if there multiple observations with `Obs.loc` share values form `Obs.date`, do the observations in `Obs.count` change? Perhaps, say, [Location U & Location X] both have observations in `Obs.date`. From this, say [Location U] has a `Obs.count` of [1] on `Obs.date` [2018-01-01] and that value increases to [2] on `Obs.date` [2018-01-02]. Lets further imagine that the opposite happens to [Location X]. I want to do this, but to the entire dataset :) I hope I explained that well.

> Created a list of `data.frame`, where each data frame is a unique date:

```r
newList<-split(b,b$Obs.date)

#output truncated...
List of 365
 $ 2018-01-01:'data.frame': 22 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Obs.date : Date[1:22], format: "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" ...
  ..$ Obs.count: int [1:22] 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
  ..$ Obs.loc  : chr [1:22] "Location U" "Location Y" "Location D" "Location E" ...
 $ 2018-01-02:'data.frame': 18 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Obs.date : Date[1:18], format: "2018-01-02" "2018-01-02" "2018-01-02" ...
  ..$ Obs.count: int [1:18] 0 0 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 4 ...
  ..$ Obs.loc  : chr [1:18] "Location V" "Location Z" "Location F" "Location V" ...
```

Hopefully, that makes it clearer. From here, I would like to see which locations appear (together) in multiple dataframes and the associated counts.

> Per comments, updating with example:

```r
#Create three different subsets, by dates:
Date1<-b %>%
  filter(Obs.date == as.Date("2018-01-01"))
Date2<-b %>%
  filter(Obs.date == as.Date("2018-01-03"))
Date3<-b %>%
  filter(Obs.date == as.Date("2018-01-05"))

#Some of the Locations have multiple observations for the same date, I am aggregating them:

FDate1<-aggregate(Obs.count~Obs.loc+Obs.date,data=Date1,FUN=sum)
FDate2<-aggregate(Obs.count~Obs.loc+Obs.date,data=Date2,FUN=sum)
FDate3<-aggregate(Obs.count~Obs.loc+Obs.date,data=Date3,FUN=sum)

#Further subset by locations that share dates across the dataframes. Here I chose two random locations (Location E & Location L)

Sample1<-FDate1 %>% filter (Obs.loc=='Location E')
Sample1B<-FDate2 %>% filter (Obs.loc=='Location E')
Sample2<-FDate1 %>% filter (Obs.loc=='Location L')
Sample2B<-FDate2 %>% filter (Obs.loc=='Location L')

#Merge the filtered locations (there has to be a less tedious way, right?)
Sample1Merge<-rbind(Sample1,Sample1B)
Sample2Merge<-rbind(Sample2,Sample2B)
FullMerge<-rbind(Sample1Merge,Sample2Merge)

#The final output:

> print(FullMerge)
     Obs.loc   Obs.date Obs.count
1 Location E 2018-01-01         2
2 Location E 2018-01-03         4
3 Location L 2018-01-01         6
4 Location L 2018-01-03         1
```

From here, we are almost there. We have our two locations that share dates, and the counts for them. Now, I want to annotate changes between the levels of `Obs.loc`.

**In this example, between the two dates, we see:**

When `Obs.loc` **Location E** increases [from 2->4] 
`Obs.loc` **Location L** decreases [from 6->1]

Thereby, we observe a negative relationship between the two levels.

> This is what I am trying to accomplish, but over the entire dataset (dataset b).

1. What levels from `Obs.loc` share the same dates.
2. Of those identified (#1), what are the observed changes, if any, in counts.

This would allow me to identify relationships within the data, that is, are counts dependent or independent of one another, when sharing multiple dates.

Comment: I updated it, please let me know if this satisfies the requirements.

Comment: can you clarify what is your anticipated result? if successful, what will you end up with exactly? what would a desired data frame look like in the end for these 40 observations?

Comment: Sure @Ben . The expected result would be a data-frame that lists the number of times that locations appear on the same date. And the associated counts. In my head, I am thinking this will be a multistep process as I not only want to identify which locations share the same date, but also track the count (and changes in) per date.

Comment: so for the example including 40 observations in exB what exactly would you want to see? For example, Location D is present 3 times on 1/1/18, with obs.count of 0, 2 and 2. Would the final result be (for 4 columns): 1/1/18, Location D, 3, 1 (where 3=total number rows and 1=number of changes observed in Obs.count on 1/1/18 for Location D)? If possible, provide a small dataframe that would contain the desired result, even if just for subset of the data.

Comment: @Ben, this is fun! First time on SO- didnt think it would be so interactive, but your comments are making me *THINK*. I am providing (another) update..think its easier.

Comment: this may be getting beyond me --- but one thing I noticed, if you want the rows together by 'Location' just add 'arrange (Obs.loc)' as you appear to be using dplyr. as for annotating changes between levels of Obs.loc, which combination of dates (all?) - the example just has 1/1 and 1/3, but locations share many dates; and do you want relationships between all locations (appear to be a lot of locations); and some dates have multiple counts (e.g., 12/9/18 Location E has 2,2,2 and 5). and do you want to add a column to indicate relationship with other locations? if so, would add to example